# Analytical solution for $\frac{x \cdot e^{-\frac{a^2}{8(1 + x^2)}} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}}{(1+x^2)^{1.5}} = \frac1{2 \sqrt{\pi} \cdot x^2}$?

Tags: calculus, roots

Proof that solution exists is here. Let $$F(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \frac{x }{(1+x^2)^{3/2}}  \exp\left(-\frac{a^2}{8(1 + x^2)} \right) - \frac1{2 \sqrt{\pi} \cdot x^2}$$ with $a$ being some fixed positive. Let calculate the limits:

1. $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} F(x) = -\infty$
2. $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to +\infty} F(x) = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \left(\frac{1 + O\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)}{x^2} - \frac1{x^2}\right) = \lim_{x \to +\infty} O\left(\frac1{x^4} \right) = +0$.

Thus, $F(x)$ has one zero-crossing point at least.

I failed to find the analytical solution for $F(x) = 0$ with help of Wolfram Mathematica. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution in terms of the Lambert W function:
$$
x=\sqrt{\frac{12W\left(\frac{a^2}{24}\exp\left(\frac{a^2}{12}\right)\right)}{\left(a^2-12W\left(\frac{a^2}{24}\exp\left(\frac{a^2}{12}\right)\right)\right)} }
$$

---

step-by-step solution:

$$
\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \frac{x }{(1+x^2)^{3/2}}  \exp\left(-\frac{a^2}{8(1 + x^2)} \right) = \frac1{2 \sqrt{\pi} \cdot x^2}
\\
2^{3/2} \frac{x^3 }{(1+x^2)^{3/2}}  \exp\left(-\frac{a^2}{8(1 + x^2)} \right) = 1
$$
Both sides raised to power $2/3$
$$
2 \frac{x^2 }{(1+x^2)}  \exp\left(-\frac{a^2}{12(1 + x^2)} \right) = 1
\\
2 \frac{x^2 }{(1+x^2)}  
\exp\left(\frac{a^2}{12}-\frac{a^2}{12(1 + x^2)} \right) 
= \exp\left(\frac{a^2}{12}\right)
\\
2 \frac{x^2 }{(1+x^2)}  
\exp\left(\frac{a^2x^2}{12(1+x^2)} \right) 
= \exp\left(\frac{a^2}{12}\right)
\\
\frac{a^2x^2 }{12(1+x^2)}  
\exp\left(\frac{a^2x^2}{12(1+x^2)} \right) 
= \frac{a^2}{24}\exp\left(\frac{a^2}{12}\right)
\\
\frac{a^2x^2 }{12(1+x^2)}  
= W\left(\frac{a^2}{24}\exp\left(\frac{a^2}{12}\right)\right)
\\
a^2x^2
= 12(1+x^2)W\left(\frac{a^2}{24}\exp\left(\frac{a^2}{12}\right)\right)
\\
x^2\left(a^2-12W\left(\frac{a^2}{24}\exp\left(\frac{a^2}{12}\right)\right)\right)
= 12W\left(\frac{a^2}{24}\exp\left(\frac{a^2}{12}\right)\right)
\\
x^2=\frac{12W\left(\frac{a^2}{24}\exp\left(\frac{a^2}{12}\right)\right)}{\left(a^2-12W\left(\frac{a^2}{24}\exp\left(\frac{a^2}{12}\right)\right)\right)}
\\
x=\sqrt{\frac{12W\left(\frac{a^2}{24}\exp\left(\frac{a^2}{12}\right)\right)}{\left(a^2-12W\left(\frac{a^2}{24}\exp\left(\frac{a^2}{12}\right)\right)\right)} }
$$

Comment: Wow! Super! Just found out about Lambert W function, thanks to your great answer.